# Error 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$id' appears in /data/app/com.example.username.projectname

Tags: android, android-studio

NoSuchFieldError in Android Studio.

This problem is occurred while running other application also. I try with other applications also.
Please help me,I can't figure out how this error is coming. Here I want to make a toolbar which have some menu items.

Error:-

```
 java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field title of type I in class 
 Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$id; or its superclasses (declaration of 
 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$id' appears in 
 /data/app/com.example.manojbudhaayer.newapplicaton-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk)
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id ==R.id.profile){

        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.setting){

        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.mylink){

        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.refresh){

       return true;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.example.manojbudhaayer.newapplicaton.MainActivity">

<include
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
 ></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

 </LinearLayout>
```

menu_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/profile"
    android:title="Profile"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item android:id="@+id/setting"
    android:title="Setting"
    android:orderInCategory="102"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item android:id="@+id/mylink"
    android:title="My fb Link"
    android:orderInCategory="103"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:title="Refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="104"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

style.xml

```
<resources>


<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because of both library and module with the same name or inflating multiple XML layouts with duplicate resource id. rename the layout in one of the modules.